# Google chrome has no connection but incognito does

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I get the error:

```
There is no Internet connection

There is something wrong with the proxy server, or the address is incorrect.
Try:
Contacting the system admin
Checking the proxy address
Running Network Diagnostics
ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED
```

But incognito works fine, all other browsers including canary works fine. How do I fix this?

Comment: I've removed your _"edit: nvm delete this"_; that's not how a Q&A works. If one of the posted answers gave you the solution [then "accept" that answer](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers). If you found a (different) answer yourself then please post it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely that you're using an extension that's interfering with proxy settings. If you happen to use a proxy connection to connect to internet then using another proxy extension is likely going to mess up with internet connectivity as is the case.

By default most Chrome extensions are disabled when using "**incognito**" mode, hence the "culprit extension" will be disabled and you have a normal internet connectivity.

Try troubleshooting which is the problematic proxy extension, y disabling them then reenable one by one until you identify it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to switch on one by one the extensions into the incognito mode. Right upper corner, three dots, More tools, Extension. Mark the checkbox "Allow in incognito".